# Как проверить, является ли элемент из list<class> пустым?

Tags: c#

есть класс item.

```
public class Item
    {
        public int id;
        public string name;
        public Sprite img;
    }
```

И есть список этих элементов

```
public List<Item> Inventory = new List<Item>();
```

Как проверить, является ли конкретный элемент, например a - пустым?

Comment: Что значит пустым? Элемент может быть в списке, может не быть. Дайте определение слову "пустым".

Comment: @aepot, под словом "Элемент" я имею ввиду ячейку листа. Мне надо проверить, находится ли в ней "Item", или нет.

Comment: в любой ячейке листа находится "Item"

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Item
{
    public int id;
    public string name;
    public Sprite img;

    /// <summary>
    /// Метод проверяет заполнены ли поля класса
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public bool IsEmpty() =>
             string.IsNullOrEmpty(name) && id < 0 && img == null
}
```

> Дальше

```
 public List<Item> Inventory = new List<Item>();
for (int i = 0; i < Inventory.Count; i++)
        {
            if (Inventory[i].IsEmpty())
            {
                //пустой
            }
            else
            {
                //не пустой
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Проверьте так

```
foreach(var item in Inventory) {
  if (item != null && string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.name) && item.img != null) {
  // do something
  }

}
```